# SQL query: list of all IDs that were active during a given time interval, sorted by their start-time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table containing the points (x/y coordinates) of tracks. Each row contains the TrackID, a Timestamp, and the X and Y Positions for that track at that given point in time.

What I want is a list of all TrackIDs that were active during a given time interval (tmin...tmax), sorted by their start-time, *even if that start time is outside the interval*.

A little illustration might help:

[image: Illustration]

As an example: Track 1 is active from t11 till t12, which means I have many rows in my table with ID=1 and with timestamps ranging from t11 to t12.

The desired output would be:

```
TrackID | StartTime
--------+-----------
    7   |    t71
    1   |    t11
    2   |    t21
    6   |    t61
```

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT TrackID, MIN(Timestamp) AS StartTime FROM Tracks WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN tmin AND tmax GROUP BY TrackID ORDER BY StartTime;
```

However, in the example above I don't get the real start times for tracks 1 and 7, since all rows with timestamps less than tmin are not considered at all.

Of course I could in a first step just get all active TrackIDs with

```
SELECT TrackID FROM Tracks WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN tmin AND tmax GROUP BY TrackID;
```

and then with separate queries find the start times of all these tracks and then sort them in my application code.

But I'm sure there is a way to do this with one SQL query. My table contains millions of rows, so efficiency is an issue here.

Comment: Even the start time is outside and what about finish time... You want the same behaviour?

Comment: I don't care about the finish time in this application.

Comment: Is it possible that start time and end time are both outside of tmin and tmax with no timestamps appearing between tmin and tmax?  If so, then your second query will have a false negative in that case.

Comment: @mellamokb: Good point! The interval tmin...tmax is large compared to the "sampling interval" of the tracks. So this should never be an issue.

Comment: If any points in time are recorded for a given track, does that mean that the track was active for the span of time between the earliest and the latest point? Or are there possible “downtimes” for a given track? If a track only has one entry, does that represent the start of an “Event” that has not yet been completed, and that may still be running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to think about it is to construct the logic to handle your four special cases in your diagram.  These two rules should suffice.

1. tend > tmin AND
2. tstart < tmax

If any of these two conditions are true, then the track should be included.  You will need a list of tracks as in your second query with their min and max values, and then perform the comparisons:

```
SELECT T.TrackID
  FROM (SELECT TrackID, MIN(Timestamp) AS StartTime, MAX(Timestamp) AS EndTime
        FROM Tracks GROUP BY TrackID) T
 WHERE T.EndTime > tmin AND T.StartTime < tmax
```

Comment: I don't have it in my query, but you can select `T.StartTime` to get the starting time, and `ORDER BY T.StartTime` to sort by the starting time of the track.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at your picture - all the ranges you want have ending time greater than `min` and starting time less than `max`.

Comment: @mellamokb I've corrected the error - just forgot to write `and starting time` less than ...

Comment: @mellamokb No point in writing a query now that you have presented yours :-)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
SELECT TrackID, MIN(Timestamp) AS StartTime FROM Tracks WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM Tracks
    WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN tmin AND tmax)
GROUP BY TrackID ORDER BY StartTime;
```

This is better I think:

```
SELECT SQUERY.TrackID, MIN(SQUERY.Timestamp) AS StartTime FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM Tracks
    WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN tmin AND tmax) AS SQUERY
GROUP BY SQUERY.TrackID ORDER BY SQUERY.StartTime;
```

Ok I'm sure this is it now :p

```
SELECT TrackID, MIN(Timestamp) AS StartTime FROM Tracks WHERE TrackID IN (
    SELECT TrackID
    FROM Tracks
    WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN tmin AND tmax)
GROUP BY TrackID ORDER BY StartTime;
```

Comment: That sounds promising. I will check it on monday!

Comment: I just realised it isnt quite right. You need to add an alias to the table in the subquery and link it to the main table. I can do this in SQL Server but I'll check first to see if it's the same in MySQL

Comment: This is pretty like my solution (that i've deleted because i've noticed a thing that i've also noticed in your answer). This will don't work. Think about this: how if t1 (that in a moment of "t" will be included into the range) have also a start AND a finish time outside the given interval ? It will be listed, and the start time could be the smaller!

Comment: Your last solution works on a small dataset but on my original (large) dataset I get a 2013 (lost connection) error after 600 seconds. I guess it's a timeout problem. mellamokbs solution takes 40 seconds on my original dataset. Can it be that your solution is that much slower? (and why?)

Comment: @RobertHegner: It partly depends on what indexes you have defined, and the density of your dataset (e.g., how many timestamps are on a single track).  My solution pulls out min and max per track which can be really fast with the proper table optimization, whereas bukko's solution pulls every timestamp that is in the range, which could be hundreds more rows in his subquery.  If you search for a really narrow tmin - tmax (say no more than one or two timestamps per track in the range), bukko's solution might actually be faster in that case.

Comment: @mellamokb: My dataset is quite dense (many timestamps per track, and also usually a wide tmin...tmax interval). I have an index on TrackID. I tried to speed up your solution by also adding an index on the timestamp column, but it made no difference. Any suggestions on how I could optimize my table for your solution?

Answer (score -1):

You were on the right track with your second query, you just need to add an `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TrackID 
FROM Tracks 
WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN tmin AND tmax 
GROUP BY TrackID 
ORDER BY Timestamp;
```

Comment: I think I will get the wrong start times for 1 and 7 with this approach. But I will check on monday.

Comment: This will give you what you asked for, "What I want is a list of all TrackIDs that were active during a given time interval (tmin...tmax), sorted by their start-time, even if that start time is outside the interval." The SELECT/WHERE returns the list of TrackIDs with associated Timestamps between the start and end which are then ordered by the minimum Timestamp.